# UserId is empty guid

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am getting following error when I am trying to resolve a case in MS Dynamics CRM Online '*UserId is empty guid!*'. There is no plugin and workflow running in the background at the time of case resolution. When I try to resolve the Case through admin, it is working fine without any error. I copied this error from browser console as Plugin Trace Log is not throwing any error. I know it is related to security roles but not able to understand which role I have to tweak.
Please find the stack-trace below.

```
error: {code: "0x80040217", message: "UserId is empty guid! ",…}
code: "0x80040217"
innererror: {message: "UserId is empty guid! ",…}
message: "UserId is empty guid! "
stacktrace: "   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.Execute(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType, Boolean checkAdminMode, ExecutionContext executionContext, Dictionary`2 optionalParameters)
↵   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataExecutionContext.Execute(OrganizationRequest request, ExecutionContext executionContext)
↵   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataServiceDataProvider.ExecuteOperation(CrmODataExecutionContext context, EdmOperation edmOperation, Dictionary`2 parameters, Dictionary`2 boundParameters)
↵   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.ActionController.ProcessOperationRequest(String operationName, Dictionary`2 operationParameters, EntityReference entityReference, String boundEntityName, String boundEntityType)
↵   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.ActionController.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<PostUnboundAction>b__0()
↵   at Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Func`1 func, IEnumerable`1 additionalCustomProperties)
↵   at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Func`1 func)
↵   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
↵   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
type: "System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]"
message: "UserId is empty guid! "
```

Error Screenshot -
[image]

Comment: That definitely looks like a custom exception, so custom code must be running somewhere.

Comment: No there is no plugin and workflow running in the background, as I have mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue, as it was due to read permission was not available in Calendar Entity in service management. I tried trial and error approach by changing the permissions of individual entities one by one. 
I don't understand why Dynamics does not throw appropriate error so that it becomes easy to resolve the issue.
[image]